# Summing digits of integers in an input file java error

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to read integers from an input file "input.txt" and separate the integers and add the digits. This code I have is giving me an error saying that the method for sum is an illegal start. Any pointers?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //declarations
    boolean fileOpened = true;
    Scanner inputFile = null;
    int sumNum, num;
    //read input
    String fileName = " ";
    System.out.println("Please input the name of the file to be opened: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    fileName = input.nextLine();

    try{
        inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("--- File NOT Found! ---");
        fileOpened = false;
    }

    if(fileOpened && inputFile.hasNext()){
        sumNum = sum(num);//method call
        while(inputFile.hasNextInt()){
            if(inputFile.hasNextInt()){
                num = inputFile.nextInt();
                System.out.println("For number " + num + " the sum of the digits is: " + sumNum);
            }
            else{
                inputFile.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public static int sum(int num){
        int i, sumNum = 0;
        for(i = 1; i <= num; i++){
            sumNum += num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return sumNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code, you are probably missing some `{` and `}`s.

Comment: And now I can see it, you didn't `}` your `main` method.

Comment: `sumNum = sum(num);//method call`, u decalred `num` but i dont see where is it initialised!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}`  in your main method. You have also not initialized your `num`.

I have fixed the main to give the right output. There were other problems in your method. You were calling the `sum` method at the wrong place. Try the answer below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //declarations
        boolean fileOpened = true;
        Scanner inputFile = null;
        int sumNum, num = 0;
        //read input
        String fileName = "";
        System.out.println("Please input the name of the file to be opened: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        fileName = input.nextLine();
        try{
          inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("--- File NOT Found! ---");
          fileOpened = false;

        }

          while(inputFile.hasNextInt()){
              num = inputFile.nextInt();
              sumNum = sum(num);//method call
              System.out.println("For number " + num + " the sum of the digits is: " + sumNum);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it and initialized my method call but now it is not reading the ".txt" file and using the integers in the file.

Comment: @anirudh : for what i see...u just summed up the comments as the answer...at least u should have pointed out where `}` is missing in `main`!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: Sorry, I was fixing the method and so did not look at your comment when I posted the answer. I've posted the fixed main method now.

Comment: That fixed the errors, except for the logical error I have that isn't allowing the "input.txt" file to be used to get the integers in order to sum. So confusing